# How to make Javascript synchronous in the main execution context?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

It's possible to make JS synchronous inside of an async funciton with async/await.

```
async function manager(){
    console.log("Loading Assets!")
    await async1()
    await async2()
    ...(more awaited async code)
    console.log("Assets Loaded!")
}
```

Is it possible to do the same thing inside of the MAIN execution context, i.e. without putting into a function?

Comment: It's not really synchronous. It's just syntactic sugar that uses promises to let you write as if it were synchronous.

Comment: There's nothing equivalent in the top-level.

Comment: You could wrap all your top-level code in an async IIFE.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you!  Marked as dupe.